# Drag item from listvew in one usercontrol to Canvas in another usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, drag-and-drop

Need to create a list of images icon with control name(below sample code) in listview need to be drag and drop to another usercontrol Canvas area. FOR Example: When we click on controls in Toolbar in Visual studio and dropping it on design area.

Expectation: When click the listview item, the cursor css should be changed till we releasing it on the canvas area, based on the binded Key value of Listview item place the control in the cursor position inside the canvaschanand drag to canvas area. And get the value binded to the item.

XAML Code:

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="tStack">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Key, Converter={StaticResource StringToImage}
 , ConverterParameter=../Images/ControlIcons/{0}.ico}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="10px"  Width="60px" Margin="2,0,0,0"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144264/wpf-listview-cursor-change
First i am trying to change the cursor css when its left button is down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link gave me solution my problem.

[Click here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c4428aa7-7f5a-4b01-a9bf-26c1bd3dbe2a/drag-controls-from-listview-using-wpf?forum=wpf&prof=required)